# when i click button,new button appears and it doesn't work

Tags: jquery, click

When i click button, i want to add new note to my db.So when i click add_note button, a textbox  and save button appears. When i click save button nothing change. I check the web concole but there is no error . What should i do ?

> jquery

```
$("#add_note").each(function() {
    $(this).on("click", function() {
        $("#not").html('<input type="text" id="note" />');
        $("#buton").html('<button  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm " id="save">Save</button>');

    });
});


$("#save").each(function() {
    $(this).on("click", function() {
        alert("dsfasdfasdfasd");
    });
});
```

> html

```
<td id="not"></td>
<td id="buton">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm " id="add_note"> Add New Note</button>
</td>
```

Comment: is there any fiddle available ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1v57nwg8/2/

Comment: @Learner thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id be unique in HTML. Use **event delegation** for dynamically added elemnets in the DOM

```
 $("#buton").on('click', '#save', function(){
   alert("dsfasdfasdfasd");
 });
```